# NLTK tokenizer ImportError: No module named copy_reg

Tags: python-3.x, nltk, importerror

Short information: I'm running python 3.0 and have NLTK installed (switched back from 3.3 because NLTK has no support for 3.3 which sucks because all other extensions I have are for 3.3)
When trying to extract named entities I get this error:

```
File "D:\UM\Programming\Thesis\Thesis\test.py", line 10, in <module>
   sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(file)
File "C:\Python30\Lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py", line 75, in sent_tokenize
   tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
File "C:\Python30\Lib\site-packages\nltk\data.py", line 630, in load
   resource_val = pickle.load(opened_resource)
File "C:\Python30\lib\pickle.py", line 1323, in load
   return Unpickler(file, encoding=encoding, errors=errors).load()
ImportError: No module named copy_reg
```

I've read somewhere else that the `ImportError` arises when dumping to a non-binary file, but in this case I'm trying to read an already dumped pickle-file. Does anyone know how to resolve the error?
The variable `file` in the mentioned line is just a `string` containing a small amount of text.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [posting](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/issues/169) nltk 3.x has still a major problem: the models in nltk in 2.x were saved using python 2.x. With the new unicode aware io system in python 3 the models have to be retrained and saved in files readable by python 3. The posting has also a link to a branch with newly trained models, but I haven't tried them yet. So basically the error message in nltk created by unpickle are caused by incompatible pickle versions between python 2 and 3. 
Edit: Actually here is a [posting](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/pull/359) why the offered fix may be not working.